# T-SQL replace NULL values in result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm at loss with this. What would be the simples way to achieve this?

I have "Customers" table like this:

```
USER_ID| NAME    | J_ID   |K_ID    |Y_ID
-----------------------------------------
    1  |  CUST1  |  A     |  1     |  AB
    2  |  CUST2  |  B     |  2     |  NULL
    3  |  CUST3  |  C     |  3     |  EF
    4  |  CUST4  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  GH
    5  |  CUST5  |  E     |  5     |  IJ
```

Then "R_ID" table like this:

```
   R_ID  | Y_ID    
------------------
    1A9  |  AB  
    2B8  |  CD  
    3C7  |  EF  
    4D6  |  GH  
    5E5  |  IJ
```

Then "JK_ID" table like this:

```
   R_ID  | J_ID | K_ID
-----------------------
    1A9  |  A  |  1
    2B8  |  B  |  2
    3C7  |  C  |  3
    4D6  |  D  |  4
    5E5  |  E  |  5
```

This is what I would like to get:

```
USER_ID| NAME    | J_ID   |K_ID    |Y_ID
-----------------------------------------
    1  |  CUST1  |  A     |  1     |  AB
    2  |  CUST2  |  B     |  2     |  CD
    3  |  CUST3  |  C     |  3     |  EF
    4  |  CUST4  |  D     |  4     |  GH
    5  |  CUST5  |  E     |  5     |  IJ
```

So I need to get the missing values from R_ID or JK_ID tables by joining those. But what is the simplest way to get that result, so that the nulls are replaced by the values from joined tables?

Answer (score 7):

One way to accomplish this is to use [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) along with [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). To get the missing values in the `J_ID` and `K_ID` column you can join to `R_ID` and `JK_ID`. To get the missing values in the `Y_ID` column you can join to `JK_ID` and `R_ID`.

Something close to the following should work:

```
SELECT
  cus.USER_ID
, cus.NAME
, COALESCE(cus.J_ID, r_to_jk.J_ID) AS J_ID
, COALESCE(cus.K_ID, r_to_jk.K_ID) AS K_ID
, COALESCE(cus.Y_ID, r_to_y.Y_ID) AS J_ID
FROM Customers cus
LEFT OUTER JOIN R_ID y_to_r ON cus.Y_ID = y_to_r.Y_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN JK_ID r_to_jk ON y_to_r.R_ID = r_to_jk.R_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN JK_ID jk_to_r ON cus.J_ID = jk_to_r.J_ID AND cus.K_ID = jk_to_r.K_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN R_ID r_to_y ON jk_to_r.R_ID = r_to_y.R_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you this works fine. If I would like to join one additional table, would this be ok to use coalesce on the last join like this: LEFT OUTER JOIN LTI_C AS LTI ON COALESCE(cus.Y_ID, r_to_y.Y_ID) = LTI.Y_ID

Answer (score 0):

```
select  c.user_id,c.name
       ,coalesce(c.j_id,jk.j_id) as j_id
       ,coalesce(c.k_id,jk.k_id) as k_id
       ,coalesce(c.y_id,r.y_id)  as y_id
from                customers c
        left join   jk_id     jk
        join        r_id      r
        on          r.r_id = jk.r_id
        on          r.y_id = c.y_id
                or  (   jk.j_id = c.j_id
                    and jk.k_id = c.k_id
                    )
```

---

```
+---------+-------+------+------+------+
| user_id | name  | j_id | k_id | y_id |
+---------+-------+------+------+------+
| 1       | CUST1 | A    | 1    | AB   |
+---------+-------+------+------+------+
| 2       | CUST2 | B    | 2    | CD   |
+---------+-------+------+------+------+
| 3       | CUST3 | C    | 3    | EF   |
+---------+-------+------+------+------+
| 4       | CUST4 | D    | 4    | GH   |
+---------+-------+------+------+------+
| 5       | CUST5 | E    | 5    | IJ   |
+---------+-------+------+------+------+
```

---

For those who are not familiar with this JOIN syntax, the following indentation and bracketing might be easier to follow.

```
select  c.user_id,c.name
       ,coalesce(c.j_id,jk.j_id) as j_id
       ,coalesce(c.k_id,jk.k_id) as k_id
       ,coalesce(c.y_id,r.y_id)  as y_id
from                customers c
        left join   (           jk_id     jk
                    join        r_id      r
                    on          r.r_id = jk.r_id
                    )
        on          r.y_id = c.y_id
                or  (   jk.j_id = c.j_id
                    and jk.k_id = c.k_id
                    )
```

---

And here is a demo for this JOIN syntax that works for **Oracle**, **SQL Server**, **PostgreSQL**, **MySQL**, **Teradata** and more.

```
create table t1 (i int);
create table t2 (i int);
create table t3 (i int);

insert into t1 (i) values (1);
insert into t1 (i) values (2);
insert into t1 (i) values (3);

insert into t2 (i) values (2);
insert into t2 (i) values (3);

insert into t3 (i) values (3);
```

---

```
select  * 
from                t1 
        left join   t2 
        join        t3 
        on          t3.i = t2.i 
        on          t2.i = t1.i
```

---

```
+---+------+------+
| i | i    | i    |
+---+------+------+
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
+---+------+------+
| 2 | NULL | NULL |
+---+------+------+
| 3 | 3    | 3    |
+---+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this would have been simple also, but there are customers who don't have match.

Comment: Check out the updated solution

Comment: @Joni: Details like that probably need to be in the question.

Comment: If you have any doubts, see updated answer.